# Tizen Studio - can't connect mac and tv

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio, tizen-sdb

I try for several days now to install Tizen Studio and install an app on a Samsung Smart Tv.

I'm on Mac right now (`mac OS X 10.9.5`), this is what I tried :

**1/ Download and installation**

I downloaded the IDE installer and the CLI installer from here : https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/tizen-studio/download?langredirect=1

First problem : the IDE installer file doesn't work, impossible to install, so I installed the CLI : looks ok.

I then opened the `package-manager` using the CLI and installed the `Tizen SDK tools` (from Main SDK) and the `TV-Extensions-5.5`, `Samsung Certificate Extension` and `TV Extensions Tools` (from Extension SDK).

**2/ Create basic app**

I tried to follow this link : https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/community/tip-tech/sample-web-application-development-using-command-line-interface

I created a sample app using PROFILE = `tv-samsung-5.5` and TEMPLATE = `BasicBasicProject`, I did the build, I generated certificate, created a security profile, I did the packaging with Signing and then I'm stuck because I can't connect my mac and the TV.

**3/ The tv part**

I put the TV on Developer Mode, I created a samsung profile on the tv and I connected the mac and the tv on the same wifi.

**4/ Device manager fail : sdb problem ? (Smart Development Bridge)**

I opened the device manager interface using CLI, clicked on Remote Device manager and used the scan devices option : it returns my TV ip. Then when I switched the connection from OFF to ON, I got this error message :

> - Server is not running. Start it now on port 26099*
> - Server has started successfully *
>     failed to connect to 172.**.***.***:26101
>
> You may get this message for following reasons:
>
> - This remote device is already connected by another one
> - This remote device is running on a non-standar port.
> - There is no IP address, please check the physical connection.

Then, I tried to use CLI with `sdb connect 172.**.***.***` and got this error :

> dyid: Registered code signature for /usr/lib/libcrypto.35.dylib
>
> - Server is not running. Start it now on port 26099 *
>
> dyId: Registered code signature for /usr/lib/libcrypto.35.dylib
>
> - Server has started successfully *
>
> error: protocol fault: no status
>
> failed to connect to 172.**.***.***:26101

I think I might have a sdb problem because when I tried : `sbt kill-server` I have a message that the server is not running, then if I do `sdb start-server` I have the same message than before with `* Server has started successfully *` but then if I try again `sbt kill-server` I still got the message `server is not running`...

And last precision : the `/usr/lib/libcrypto.35.dylib` file was missing when I first tried the command so I find it on internet and add it myself.

**Do you have any idea to make it works please ? Am I missing something ?**

I tried with sdk 8, 12, 13 and never manage to make it works, right now I have `java 1.8.0_241`, `javac 1.8.0_241` and `Tizen CLI 2.5.16`

If you need more information I will edit my question.

Comment: I tried for a while on macOS but failed and gave up. I also tried using a Windows 10 box for a while, but failed there as well and gave up. I have to say I think pretty low of Java as a whole and Tizen in particular.  I'd really like to be able to debug the Samsung Internet Browser on my Samsung Smart-TV though. It feels like with a few more steps it might just work. Sorry to be of no real help at this time, but if I ever find out anything I'll try to post back here. Oh, and just to be clear, I am not creating a "native app" per se, I'm just trying to debug my web site in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Kill all processes that use 26099 port

```
sudo lsof -i:26099
```

and then kill them by their PID

```
kill [PID]
```

Answer (score 2):

When enabling developer mode on your device (e.g. TV) make sure you enter your computer's IP address in the "Host PC IP" section. The default is as 0.0.0.0, which is easy to miss.

Leaving it this way will lead to the `the remote device is already connected to another` error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to combine both answers from here:

- Kill all processes using the 26099 port and
- Make sure that the correct IP address is set in the "HOST PC IP" section
  [image]